# Encrypting and decrypting in python without using special characters

Tags: python

I would like to encrypt certain strings and use them in a HTTP GET protocol without resulting in an error if there are special characters in URL. Any advice on how can I convert strings to an encryption of that sort and decrypt it again? what encryption library would be most suitable for this scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encrypt and decrypt using a standard encryption algorithm (from a library), and encode the encrypted sting using base 64 (from the `base64` module).

Your workflow becomes:

1. Encrypt the *plaintext* using a crypto library (gives you the *ciphertext*)
2. Encode the *ciphertext* using base 64 (gives you an *encoded ciphertext*, this is URL proof)
3. Decode the *encoded ciphertext* using base 64 (gives you the *ciphertext* back)
4. Decrypt the *ciphertext* using a crypto library (gives you the *plaintext* back)

---

A few encryption libraries:

- [`m2crypto`](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto)
- [`pycrypto`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/)
- [`pynacl`](https://pynacl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: On a more general note - anything that's encoded base64 will be safe to pass over a query string or in a URL.